# Is anyone aware of Du atallah multiplicative secret sharing scheme for dot products for > 2 party scenario?

Tags: secret-sharing

I am working on Du Atallah's multiplicative secret sharing scheme for more than 2 party scenario.

Is anyone aware of its multiparty version (more than 2 parties).

The paper for 2 party can be found in Section 4.1 of [this link](https://www.cerias.purdue.edu/assets/pdf/bibtex_archive/2001-02.pdf).

Comment: Have you contacted the authors of the paper?